# Error: request for member 'RGB' in 'redLed' , which is of non-class type 'int'

Tags: programming

My 10 year old received great gift from older brother (Crate Creations) and I am trying write the program and getting this error. It looks to me that I matched the required code word for word symbol for symbol but I just can't figure out what I did wrong:

```
void loop () {

  for (float x = 0; x < PI; x = x + 0.00001) {
    RGB[0] = power * abs(sin(x * (CommonMathVariable)));
    RGB[1] = power * abs(sin((x + PI/3) * (CommonMathVariable)));
    RGB[2] = power * abs(sin((x + (2 * PI) / 3) * (CommonMathVariable)));
    ambientLight = analogRead(ldrPin);
    if (ambientLight > 600) {

    analogWrite (redLed.RGB[0]);
    analogWrite (greenLed.RGB[1];
    analogWrite (blueLed.RGB[2];

  }
```

I get this error:

```
request for member 'RGB' in 'redLed' , which is of non-class type 'int'
```

Comment: Nick,  Thanks so much...that got me past the error i have been stressing over... the booklet just looks like a period and not a comma....you rock..here is the rest of the code...after i corrected the comma i am getting an error for 'pulseSpeed not declared'

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

  if (RGB[i] < 1)  {
    delay (20 * pulseSpeed); 
  }

  else if (RGB[i] < 5)  {
    delay (10 * pulseSpeed); 
  }

  else if (RGB[i] < 10)  {
    delay (2 * pulseSpeed);
  }
  else if (RGB[i] < 100)  {
  delay  (1 * pulseSpeed);
}

else {}
}

delay (1);
}

Comment: I can't really make out that comment. This sounds like a different question. Can you make a new one please? On the face of it you **haven't** declared pulseSpeed, unless there is more code you haven't shown. A declaration looks like: *type* *name*, for example: `int pulseSpeed;`

Answer (score 3):

Probably you didn't spot commas:

```
    analogWrite (redLed,   RGB[0]);
    analogWrite (greenLed, RGB[1]);
    analogWrite (blueLed,  RGB[2]);
```

The function `analogWrite` takes two arguments, separated by commas. You were missing some brackets as well.